# Linux Server has 5GB free size still available space is zero and showing 100% usage

Tags: linux

As my server space was get full,I have deleted some files from my server about 5GB.

My question is:

1. Why available space is still 0(zero) ?
2. Why use is still 100% ?

I have restarted server after deleting the file.

Am I missing something else?

[image: df -h]

Comment: What kind of filesystem? Post **mount** output. Only if you give enough information you will get a useful answer.

Comment: It is linux server(plesk server).

Comment: Screenshots are ugly. Use copy-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The files aren't actually removed if they are still open somewhere. Use `lsof` to find the files.

  ```
  sudo lsof | grep deleted
  ```

  The second column in the output gives you `PID` for the process that holds the file open.
- The `df` doesn't show the space reserved for root. You can adjust this space with [`tune2fs -m`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs).
- If you used GUI to remove the files, they might be in trash bin.

Comment: OP claimed to have rebooted the server. This should get rid of open file handles.

Comment: @Sven. That's why the other options. However, the first one is the usual case. :)

Comment: I had tried with lsof. :) Thanks for the answer. Its really helpful and 
2nd point is the new information for me thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is a ext4 or xfs filesystem with 5% reserved blocks? That would amount to more than ~7,8GB to be free, to be able to write with normal user permissions.

If writing with superuser (root) rights, writing a file should work out (if I´m guessing right, that is). You could try that with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/test bs=1M count=10`, this will write a 10MB file to `/`.

I will update the answer to be more specific as soon as I know what kind of filesystem you have mounted there (e.g. using `tune2fs` to change the reserved blocks).

Comment: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/test bs=1M count=10, this will write a 10MB file to /.
What do you mean by write a file to root folder? 10MB? I am not getting

Comment: You could have written it anyplace else, too. It was to test if you could write some data with superuser rights. I had to make sure, that the file is written to the problematic filesystem. If you post the output from `mount`, I might be able to tell you the real answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running some kind of software that writes to the disk?
Maybe the disk just filled up while you were deleting the files.

Have a look where your space has gone:

`du -mx / > /run/du-m
sort -n /run/du-m`

`du -mx /` will write a list of directories with sizes in megabytes to /run/du-m (the tmpfs still has space for that). `sort -n` will then show you the directories that eat up all the space one by one, so you can go figure out what is going on.

Comment: If the disk is filled up while deleting then after restarting the server it should have shown me correct space. I am sure that there is no script running which writes on the disk continuously. I do have to perform some actions to write on the disk.

Anyway I have deleted log files from the server root folder and It worked! Thanks for the answer buddy! :)

Answer (score 0):

After spending so much time behind this issue I got the solution. May be its not a solution but It worked! I have deleted server log files from the following path

> `/var/www/vhosts/system/{domain-name}/logs`

I was deleting the file from the following path before,which was not getting affected .

> `/var/www/vhosts/{domain-name}/logs`

After that I have deleted log files which was about 73GB. Now Site is working well.

But I still wonder why it was happening so. May be it was issue of junk files of server. I must say less knowledge of server took my much time in solving the problem.